# How to store rrd file into influxdb

Tags: rrdtool, rrd, ganglia, influxdb

I'm using `ganglia` for monitoing. `ganglia` store its data as `rrd` file.

It is `rrd` files that stores metrics data on `gmetad`. Usually the default path is `/var/lib/ganglia/rrds/<cluster-name>/<node-name>/` where each metric is stored in a single `rrd` file like `bytes_in.rrd`.

Is there any way to use this `rrd` data in `influxdb`?

Comment: Push!
Has anyone a generic solution for migration rrd data to influxdb?